# Isolate less styles to react component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, less

I am trying to figure out how to get my react components to not pick up the css classes of another react component.  So say I have a component called Home and one called About, and on the inside they both just contain a div with a className of header-container and their less imports like so:

Home:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './home.less';

class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='header-container'>
                <h1>Home</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

About:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './about.less';

class About extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='header-container'>
                <h1>About</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default About;
```

And the less file for each looks like so with different colors (For this example lets say this is the about.less file):

```
.header-container {
    color: red;
}
```

Now when I use the react-router-dom and try to navigate to the home page, I am seeing the word Home but with the red color that is in the about less file, instead of the blue in my home.less file.

This is how I am navigating to the components

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './home/home';
import About from './about/about';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
                    <Route path='/about' component={About}/>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Anybody have any suggestions on how I can seperate these to not affect eachother?  Not sure if it helps, but when I am seeing this I am running webpack-dev-server to serve the files.

Edit:
Also I noticed when I inspect element on the page loaded, I am seeing the following css in my head element.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If it's going to be in the same app and you want to use an external style sheet, it's recommended that you name the two `div`s differently.

e.g. `<div className='about-page__header-container'>` `<div className='home-page__header-container'>`

This is because the css styles imported as the style sheet are global.

An alternative would be to use inline style, which is becoming increasingly popular in `React.js` community.

For a comparison of the two options, see [The Debate Around "Do We Even Need CSS Anymore?"](https://css-tricks.com/the-debate-around-do-we-even-need-css-anymore/)

Comment: That was a good read, so it seems if I wish to have isolated styling per react component, I need to utilize the inline styling and keep the css in my javascript for that component.  Still on the wire about if I prefer to continue seperating styling into its own files vs inline dynamic ;) styling.  Also changing the class names is ideal, would have been cool to find a way to implement this isolation though.

Comment: That is a long known issue with CSS, and is why people came up with naming conventions like BEM. I switched to inline styling (I use a library called `jss`), and I'd say it's worth giving it a try :)